# How change pseudo element height during rotation based on rotation degree?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, pseudo-element

I have a div container which has before and after pseudo elements, where the before pseudo element is another container which is supposed to rotate in the center of its parent element so that it crease an effect where the borders of the parent elements are rotation clockwise. The rotation part works fine but I can't wrap my head around how can I make it so that before pseudo element changes its height depending on whether it is vertically  or horizontally aligned with its parent element. I need this so that when they are horizontally aligned, the height of the pseudo element is smaller thus only the left and right borders of the parent element have a light around them. When the pseudo element is vertically aligned to its parent then its height should be bigger so more of the top and bottom area of the borders have light. I will put screenshots below to better explain that. My issue primarily comes from the shape of my parent elements which has a big width but small height while most examples of this effect are made on a square with 4 equal sides and there you don't need dynamic height.

[image]

Here is my code where currently I am calculating the rotation degree but it seems this is not the correct way or at least I do not apply this properly but I am rather lost to what is the problem.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";

const Box = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 510px;
    height: 90px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */

  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    /* width: ${(props) => props.rotationDegree * 0.6 + 200}px;
    height: ${(props) => props.rotationDegree * 0.8 + 150}%; */
    width: 500px;
    /* height: 80%; */
    /* height: ${(props) => {
      const h_max = 500; // Adjust as required
      const h_min = 100; // Adjust as required
      return (
        h_min +
        (h_max - h_min) *
          Math.abs(Math.sin(props.rotationDegree * (Math.PI / 180))) +
        "%"
      );
    }}; */

    height: ${(props) => {
      const h_max = 300; // This represents the maximum height. Adjust as required.
      const h_min = 20; // This represents the minimum height. Adjust as required.
      return (
        h_min +
        (h_max - h_min) *
          Math.abs(Math.sin(props.rotationDegree * (Math.PI / 180))) +
        "%"
      );
    }};

    background: linear-gradient(#00ccff, #d500f9);
    /* animation: ${(props) => keyframes`
      from {
        transform: rotate(${props.rotationDegree}deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(${props.rotationDegree + 360}deg);
      }
    `} 4s linear infinite; */

    animation: ${(props) => keyframes`
      from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    `} 4s linear infinite;
  }

  &::after {
    /* content: ${(props) => props.rotationDegree}; */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #0e1538;
    inset: 5px;
    border-radius: 16px;
  }
`;

function App() {
  const [rotationDegree, setRotationDegree] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setRotationDegree((prevDegree) => (prevDegree + 1) % 360);
    }, 4000 / 360); // 4000ms divided by 360 degrees

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Box rotationDegree={rotationDegree}>{/* Content inside the Box */}</Box>
      <span>{rotationDegree}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```